# Laravel 5.3.19 Illuminate\Support\Str::class error syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3, illuminate-container

I got error when i use Str from Alliases

Aliases Declaration:

```
    'Str' => Illuminate\Support\Str::class,
```

Usages:

```
<p>{{ Str::limit($notice->description,100)}}</p>
```

Error Type:

```
FatalErrorException in aae7b22b68f86ae3874e1bac917a810813cbf059.php line 380: syntax error, unexpected ';'
```

Comment: You should check error in the compiled version of your blade, like in aae7b22b68f86ae3874e1bac917a810813cbf059.php line 380

Comment: try with just str_limit($notice->description, 100) helper function